# How to group elements of a nested list?

Tags: r

I would like to group the elements of a nested list in R, what is the best solution to do that ?

```
nest1 <- list(item1 = 1, item2 = "a")
nest2 <- list(item1 = 3, item2 = "b")
li <- list(nest1, nest2)
> li
[[1]]
[[1]]$item1
[1] 1

[[1]]$item2
[1] "a"


[[2]]
[[2]]$item1
[1] 3

[[2]]$item2
[1] "b"
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this :

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$item1
[[1]] 1 3

[[1]]$item2
[[1]] "a" "b"
```

I have try with `lapply` in several ways but it doesn't gives the expected result.

```
lapply(li, "[[", c("item1", "item2"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `transpose`

```
library(purrr)
transpose(li) %>%
     map(~unlist(., recursive = FALSE)) %>%
     list()
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$item1
#[1] 1 3


#[[1]]$item2
#[1] "a" "b"
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
v1 <- unlist(li)
list(lapply(split(unname(v1), names(v1)), type.convert, as.is = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using base:

```
as.list(do.call(rbind, lapply(li, data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))

# $item1
# [1] 1 3
# 
# $item2
# [1] "a" "b"
```